# Docker on Windows server and multiple websites listening port 80 and 443

Tags: windows, docker, asp.net-core, windows-server-2016

When installing ASP.NET Core apps on a windows machine, I used to install the websites within IIS, I used the bindings there to route depending on the URL to the correct web application and I used Letsencrypt to create the SSL certificates.

Now I want to start shipping my applications using Docker. The samples show, how to easily create an ASP.NET Core dockerized project, but that's where most of them end. So in the end I've got an ASP.NET application in my docker running listening on port 5000.

Are there any suggestion or resources showing how to set it up on a production system?

- multiple web sites listening on the standard ports 80 and 443 and forwaring to the correct docker image
- SSL certificate handling

Answer (score 0):

Setup [`ngingx`](https://nginx.org/ru/) as a front end. It is world-class solution, used by top-traffic sites as a front-end for incoming requests.

Among other features it does:

- Redirecting based on plenty of rules
- SSL management (you can use unencrypted connections behind it)
- Load balancing

It is free and available as docker image.

So, you open only `ngingx` outside your docker network, and make it route all your traffic inside.

Answer (score 0):

Setup reverse proxy like nginx, even in IIS also you redirect to corresponding docker service having a particular port. You can fan out traffic to respective ports.
[image]

Image: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/